# The tool "Handlers/emails" missing from YAML Forms

Tags: forms, drupal-8

I have installed the module YAML Forms in Drupal 8. According to this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rMxU-d8vanc, there is supposed to be a tool called "Emails/handlers" there beside some more. None of these show in my installation of YAML Forms. Does anyone know why?

[image]

Comment: Have you turned module on? Go to structure -> Yaml form, are forms inside?

Comment: BTW, read module description: "If you are new to the YAML Form module, do not download and install it, please download and install the latest Webform 8.x-5.x release. (It is the exact same code base as the latest YAML Form 8.x-1.x release)."